# Graphing Bar Graphs in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and am just trying to graph some plots using the ggplot2 function that I just learned with the palmer penguins dataset. I want to create a simple bar graph with species at the x-axis and average body mass at the y-axis. I begin by grouping the penguins by species and calculating the average as follow:

```
avg_body_mass <- penguins %>%
  drop_na(body_mass_g) %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarize(mean(body_mass_g))
```

This results in a new data frame that looks like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz24r.png
The first problem is: How do I change the name of the average body mass column so it is not called "mean(body_mass_g)"?

The following is my code for the graph:

```
ggplot(data = penguins) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = species, y = avg_body_mass))
```

Alternatively, I also tried this:

```
ggplot(data = avg_body_mass) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = species, y = mean(body_mass_g)))
```

I don't think I should put a mean function in the geom_bar, but that's the name of the column and I don't know how to change it.

Comment: `... %>% summarize(mean_mass = mean(body_mass_g))`. Replace `mean_mass` with the name you want.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised that I didn't even try something so obvious...